# What is the intersection of Spin(7) and U(4)?

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, holonomy

I'm just curious from Berger's classification of Riemannian holonomy, how do Spin(7) manifolds intersect the other types of Riemannian manifolds?

In particular, what is the intersection of Spin(7) and U(4), seen as subgroups of SO(8)?

Comment: I would say it is $SU(4)$, since $SU(4)\subset Spin(7)$. In fact, $SU(4)$ is another of the few holonomy groups admissible for an irreducible Riemannian manifold of dimension eight.

Comment: Of course, this depends on which conjugates of $\mathrm{Spin}(7)$ and $\mathrm{U}(4)$ in $\mathrm{SO}(8)$ you choose to intersect.  For instance, is not true that all the conjugates of $\mathrm{SU}(4)$ lie inside some fixed conjugate of $\mathrm{Spin}(7)$

Comment: @Bilateral and Robert Bryant: thank you both.

Comment: So Spin(7) does not contain U(4) right? And if I am allowed to ask more: I suppose there are Ricci-flat 8-manifolds that are not Spin(7)?

Comment: The maximal abelian subgroups of $\mathrm{Spin}(7)$ all have dimension $3$, so it cannot contain even the maximal torus of $\mathrm{U}(4)$, let alone the whole thing.  Yes, there are Ricci-flat Riemannian $8$-manifolds with holonomy not contained in $\mathrm{Spin}(7)$.  I'm not aware of a compact one, though.

Comment: @Robert Bryant: thank you very much!